# awk print command with condition of NR > var

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying with `awk` to modify some txt files using this code

```
awk -F":" '/^title/ { o=FNR+2 } ;FNR>o { print sprintf("%-10s %-10d %-10s",FILENAME,o,$0) }' r.txt
```

but it didn't work until I replace the condition as this `FNR>5`.

So tried a lot here but I didn't find out the solution. I put `"FNR>o"` & `FNR>$o` but nothing.

So guys can someone help me here !
input  :

```
date: 22.01.2020
name : xrgsm02
title : RCV20
----------------
----------------
15   20
30   40
50   12
55   77
```

output

```
r.txt   5  15   20
r.txt   5  30   40
r.txt   5  50   12
r.txt   5  55   77
```

Comment: The code looks for a line that starts with the string `title`, and will output data from two lines down from that onwards.  If there is another line with the string `title` at the start, it will again skip two lines down before outputting anything. You haven't said anything about what the data looks like that you're running this on nor have you said what's "not working", or how you'd want it to work.

Comment: there is no 2 lines start with the string 'title'  and for the input i think it's not necessarily in this case i just didn't find out the true syntax as a condition of NR>o that's it

Comment: i idited it so you can find now an exp of what i'm facing here . thank you for your help !

Comment: @DjabriJosef Welcome! You need to do more explaining, and for example, you added "EXP": what does it mean? Don't assume we understand the details, the whats and the whys. What doesn't work? What do you want to accomplish? "A to B". Explain "A", explain "to" and explain "B". Folks around here are happy to help, but not so much if they have to be guessing what the question is about.

Comment: srsly ! EXP= exemple ! i deleted it

Comment: Thanks for your edits. It is still a bit unclear what the meaning of "didn't work" is. Is the issue that your code is printing the first and second lines too, while your aim is to print from the sixth line on?

Comment: the code print here the whole file and o ana filename and not from the line 5 so nr>o he can't know that o is 5 when i put 5 in place of o the code work just fine

Comment: Uninitialized variables have a numeric value of `0`. Before a line that matches `/^title/` is encountered, `FNR>o` reads "`FNR` greatest than 0".

Comment: plz put a code that can help me not just idea !

Comment: Does something like this solve your issue? `awk -F":" '/^title/ { start = FNR + 2; go = 1 } go && FNR > start { print sprintf("%-10s %-10d %-10s",FILENAME,start,$0) }'`

Comment: amazing ! but how it works i can't find the reason , would you please explain to me  fra-san

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem:

```
FNR>o
```

- Using the `>` operator with an uninitialized value

  - Whilst `o` is uninitialized, it has a numeric value of `0` and a string value of the empty string
  - In your script, `o` is set with `/^title/ { o=FNR+2 }`, but `/^title/` doesn't appear until the third record. So for the first two records `o` is uninitialized and `FNR>o` evaluates to `true` (because `FNR==1` & `FNR==2` are `greater than zero`)

Possible solution:

```
o && FNR>o
```

- Specify that `o` must be non-zero, in addition to `FNR>o`

---

Also, `o` is somewhat confusing as a single-letter variable name – consider using a letter like `n` or a more descriptive word like `output` instead

---

```
print sprintf("%-10s %-10d %-10s",FILENAME,o,$0)
```

could be simplified to:

```
printf("%-10s %-10d %-10s\n",FILENAME,o,$0)
```

or even:

```
printf "%-10s %-10d %-10s\n",FILENAME,o,$0
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for additional info on ways to print after a match in other contexts.